# How to solve maven 2.6 resource plugin dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, m2eclipse

ERROR:

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

Solutions Tried:

Updated project: not able to download from REPO of maven.

Tried putting perticular jar in that folder of .m2 repo.

Can provide references if you want.

Comment: Looks like proxy/firewall issue?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Seems your `settings.xml` file is missing your .m2 (local maven repo) folder.

When using eclipse navigate to Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings -> Browse to your `settings.xml` and click apply.

Then do maven Update Project.

[image]

Comment: is Pom.xml file same as setting.xml file? POM.xml file contains all the dependencies. should i select POM.xml file?

Comment: no pom.xml file belongs to project, settings.xml is a part of maven

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse. How to resolve this issue outside of Eclipse?

Answer (score 17):

Right Click on Project go to -> Maven -> Update project ->select Force update project check box and click on Finish.

Answer (score 8):

I have faced the same issue. Try declaring missing plugin in the conf/settings.xml.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>           
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>   
</build>
```

Answer (score 7):

On windows:

1. Remove folder from C:\Users\USER.m2
2. Close and open the project or force a change on file: pom.xml for saving :)

Comment: I wanted to use this instead of opening project in eclipse, but unfortunately didn't work for me

Answer (score 6):

If a download fails for some reason Maven will not try to download it within a certain time frame (it leaves a file with a timestamp).

To fix this you can either

- Clear (parts of) your .m2 repo
- Run maven with -U to force an update

Comment: For the force update there is an option in eclipse that will do, right ?

Comment: Okay the same error persists even after we provide force update.I'm using eclipse.

Comment: I'm not sure how Eclipse handles this, could you run `mvn install -U` from the command line?

Comment: Installing Maven can be done with this [guide](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) an alternative to Maven would be [gradle](https://gradle.org/)

Answer (score 4):

Step 1 : Check the proxy configured in eclipse is correct or not ?
(Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections).

Step 2 : Right Click on Project-> Go to Maven -> Update the project

Step 3: Run as Maven Install.

==== By Following these steps, i am able to solve this error.

Comment: what settings we are supposed to have under `Network Connections`?

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the same issue for me:
My eclipse is installed in `/usr/local/bin/eclipse`

1) Changed permission for eclipse from root to owner: `sudo chown -R $USER eclipse`

2) Right click on `project/Maven` right click on `Update Maven` select `Force update maven project`

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error. My network is an internal one of a company. The proxy has been disabled from the IT team so for that we do not have to enable any proxy settings. I have commented the proxy setting in settings.xml file from the below mentioned locations C:\Users\vijay.singh.m2\settings.xml
  
This fixed the same issue for me

Answer (score 1):

```
This issue is happening due to change of protocol from http to https for central repository. please refer following link for more details. https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334-Central-501-HTTPS-Required 

In order to fix the problem, copy following into your pom.ml file. This will set the repository url to use https.

<repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error. My network is an internal one of a company. I downloaded neon-eclipse for java developpers. These steps worked for me:

1- I downloaded a VPN client on my PC to be totally blinded from the network. [Shellfire](https://www.shellfire.net/) I used. Use free account and connect to Shellserver.

2- Inside the windows firewall, I added incoming rule for Eclipse. Navigate to where eclipse exe is found.

3- Perform Maven Update project.

Then the project was able to fetch from the maven repository.

hope it helps.

Comment: what incoming rule you added for Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything. I deleted m2e and installed m2e version 2.7.0. Then deleted the .m2 directory and force updated maven. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project under Package Explorer > Maven > Update Project > Select the checkbox that reads "Force updates of Snapshot/Releases" > Click on OK

This way you don't have to search around for your maven's settings.xml and if the cause is something else eclipse will automatically handle it whatever it may be. [Expected path for user settings XML is shown by eclipse under: Window > Preferences > Maven > User Settings > User Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfBh3.png) (it is most likely, greyed out).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

mvn -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 install

Comment: Would you like to explain how that works and why it helps to solve the problem?
Or are you just confirming (part of) one of the other existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved by deleting the project that i created and then deleted the M2 folder in the local.

Comment: improve your answer with more details about the solution. The project you deleted were the one with the issue or another that caused it? After deleting, what were the next steps: you recreated the project? you just build it again? The current state of the answer is not enough to solve the problem! With more details is easier to understand!

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue and resolved by updating below

1. Java version
2. download and set up latest maven version
3. double check the mvn and java class path in environments variable
4. Run the mvn commands as Admin on console.
5. take backup of existing m2 repository and created new .m folder

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jenkins and Sonatype Nexus repository :

1. Update pom.xml :

   ```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   ```

---

2. Update the Maven version in  Jenkins --> Manage Jenkins --> Tools : Maven verion 3.2.5
3. Login to Jenkins server and remove .m2 folder ( /jenkins/.m2/)

---

4. Login to Sonatype and check whether Proxy URL is http or https.
   Use these URLs only for Maven Proxy :
   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
   -- OR--
   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Answer (score -1):

If you're connected to VPN, disconnect and then try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).