# Eclipse Java project build errors with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to setup a project from a svn repo on my eclipse IDE. When ever I try to build the project I'm thrown with the following error.

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Maven
>   Project Builder' on project 'ats'. Could not calculate build plan:
>   Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
>   Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
>   Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

In order to setup Maven for this project, I've ran the following command on *cmd*

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Upon running the following, Maven throws a build error with the following info.

> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 03:10 min [INFO] Finished at:
>   2015-07-30T09:51:07-04:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/122M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'eclipse' in the current project
>   and in the p lugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins,
>   org.codehaus.mojo] available from the re positories [local
>   (C:\Users\user.m2\repository), central (https://repo.mave
>   n.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full
>   stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit ch. [ERROR]
>   Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please rea d the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundF
>   orPrefixException

Has anyone ran in to this issue in the past that they can help me out with? I'm on Windows 7 64bit.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Aren't you behind a proxy that disallows you to go to Maven Central? If yes, you either need to configure Maven to be proxy-aware, or use your company's mirror repository.

Comment: @Slanec I have all my proxy info already in the settings.xml file and still getting hit by this error every time. Any ideas?

Comment: Is is being used? Run with debug info enabled: `mvn compile -X` and take a look at the output. It should tell you which settings it uses, whether it is able to connect etc.

Comment: This problem has been solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316339/how-to-solve-maven-2-6-resource-plugin-dependency