# Error in pom.xml while creating maven project in eclipses

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

[image]

i try to google but didn't find the appropriate answer

what is wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

Its a maven dependencies problem

Need to tell eclipse the local maven repository path. can be very based on platform (linux/ windows).

Refer to this : [How to solve maven 2.6 resource plugin dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316339/how-to-solve-maven-2-6-resource-plugin-dependency)

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate, just flag to cote as such. We don't need more posts about the same topic. Keep the information in a single place, not spread out across Stack Overflow.