# Error while running nodejs project on jenkins

Tags: node.js, maven, jenkins

Can someone help please I'm running nodejs project on jenkins and I got this error :

```
[INFO] Building node-js-project::server::node-js-project-appli 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.8-beta is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] node-js-project .................................... SUCCESS [  1.002 s]
[INFO] node-js-project::delivery .......................... SUCCESS [  3.013 s]
[INFO] node-js-project::server ............................ SUCCESS [  0.256 s]
[INFO] node-js-project::server::node-js-project-appli ..... FAILURE [  0.101 s]
[INFO] node-js-project::common ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] node-js-project::common::vertxstub ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.983 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-08T10:54:17+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/28M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "nexus" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.8-beta or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.8-beta in file:///var/lib/jenkins/workspace/node/node-Build on demand/trunk/server/test-project-appli/../../../repository/maven was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of node-js-project-local-plugin-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried to delete folder `C:\Users\sam\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resources-plugin` but it doesn't work.
I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316339/how-to-solve-maven-2-6-resource-plugin-dependency) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try with the `-U` switch added, like shown here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update

Comment: Thks for your answer. I tried this command : mvn clean install -U like suggest in your link but I got the same error

Comment: This is not possible. The `-U` switch resolves *update interval of ... has elapsed or updates are forced* so you cannot have the same error. Please post the nex error after that.

Comment: I really got the same error you can see this output I printed my maven command :Running in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/node/node-Build on demand/trunk
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[trunk] Running shell script
+ mvn clean install -U
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

Comment: It is impossible for that error: *[ERROR] ... Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.8-beta in ... was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of node-js-project-local-plugin-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]* to be there with the `-U` flag. Not possible since it is the purpose of this flag to resolve it. Can you paste your new logs with this flag added?

Comment: Oh sorry you are right I got this error : 
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.8-beta or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.8-beta in node-js-project-local-plugin-repo (file:///var/lib/jenkins/workspace/node/node-Build on demand/trunk/server/test-project-appli/../../../repository/maven) ->

Comment: Well it looks like you configured your Maven project to fetch only dependencies from a local repo, and that dependency isn't there, so it fails. Question is: why are you not fetching from Maven central?

Comment: I don't really know the difference

Comment: Is it possible to find it from maven central and register it in my local repo ?

Comment: @Tunaki are you there ? :)

Comment: do you have any profile in your settings.xml or in you pom.xml

Comment: Here is a part of my pom.xml :

Comment: <profiles>
  <profile>
   <id>prod</id>
   <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
   </activation>
   <properties>
    <pf.target>prod</pf.target>
   </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
   <id>tu</id>
   <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
   </activation>
   <properties>
    <pf.target>tu</pf.target>
    <grunt.task>unit</grunt.task>
   </properties>
  </profile>
 </profiles>

Comment: are you sure with this plugin version 2.8-beta look at my answer update for link

Answer (score 0):

if you use -P nexus to Maven which means "there is a profile called nexus; find it and activate it". Check your environment and your settings.xml for this flag and also look at all  elements inside the various XML files

i think you have a profile named nexus if it's true do that :

```
<activeProfiles>
  <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Usually, mvn help:effective-pom is also useful to see what the real POM would look like.

So,

i can't find maven-resources-plugin with 2.8-beta version can you look at maven repo in the link below and use the appropriate version of your plugin and retry.

[maven-resources-plugin](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/)