# Maven project plugin dependency error

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy, setup-project, m2eclipse

I'm get an error when attempting to create a Maven new Maven project in Eclipse Java Neon using the "Create Simple Archetype" setting(This is my first attempt at making a Maven project so I didn't want to try the advanced settings). I'm leaving the parent project fields blank. The error message that I get:

```
Could not calculate build plan: plugin
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 
or one of its dependencies could not be resolved. 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

I've googled my issues and found some things relating to proxy. I don't think I'm using a proxy, but I'm at work so my company could have something set up. Is there a way to check?

I also came across some things relating to the .m2 repository. Being new to Maven, I have literally no idea what this is or how to find it.

Thanks in advance to everyone for their help!

**Edit:** I have discovered that my .m2/repository folder is missing settings.xml. Is this a problem? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: It seems that your maven configuration is faulty. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31316682/6825678

Comment: You're absolutely right. There is no settings.xml file inside my repository folder. How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't think settings.xml is at fault. I might be mistaken but I don't think it is really necessary. I'd check the proxy idea first. Just run your build the same as before but add `-X` to it; this should allow you to see the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy over the settings.xml which is part of your maven installation. See: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

If you have to adjust the settings.xml later on you can do it based on that template.