# Maven import project errors

Tags: java, maven, import, project, m2e

When I import a maven project, I get a window titled "Multiple problems have occured".

Two problems:

- Building workspace

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(project name)'.

- Importing Maven projects

An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException

I've searched a bit for these errors and some people are saying it goes away by deleting ".settings" and ".project" files but this is not working for me.

What could cause these errors and is there a fix?

Comment: Does that project build on command line without any issue?

Comment: The errors are too generic to be able to tell much. In my experience, `m2e` does throw some of these, but you should be able to get a more detailed message, either in eclipse's error logs, or in `Error`/`Problems` eclipse views. Maven Console might also be telling you something more. Could you have a look and update your question with details?

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on the ide you are using. If you are using IntelliJ Idea to import the maven project just delete the existing idea related file and import the project from the beginning. If you are using Eclipse ide, this error may cause due to missing of `settings.xml` file in .m2 (local maven repo) folder.

1. In Eclipse navigate to Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings -> Browse to your `settings.xml` and click apply.
2. Then do maven Update Project.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316339/how-to-solve-maven-2-6-resource-plugin-dependency)

Comment: I am using Eclipse. The settings.xml file is there. Still doesn't work...