# Could not create maven project in eclipse IDE(oxygen)

Tags: m2eclipse

[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M91nI.jpg)
**i could not create maven project in eclipse IDE.**
i am getting the error in the image and as well as mentioned below

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6**

**i have tried following:**

---

1. deleted the folders and files under .m2/repositary and it did not work
2. windows->preferences->maven->user settings->and pointed the settings.xml to the downloaded apache maven 3.5.2 and it also did not work.
3. created the settings.xml under .m2/repositary ,it also did not work.

environment variable also set for maven(maven_home and m2_home) and java_home.

**i have googled and tried all these but could not resolve this issue.**

any help would be appreciated .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to use `.m2/repository`, not `.m2/repositary`

Check that your [`settings.xml` is correctly set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31316682/6309), with at least:

```
<mirror>
    <id>Central</id>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

Then check in a `CMD` (meaning outside) Eclipse, if:

- `M2_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` are also correctly set there
- `java -version` does return the expected version
- `mvn -version` does return the expected version
- you can download the artifact:

For the last point, you actually can execute a `mvn` command, anywhere you want (no need for a pom.xml)

```
cd c:\
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:get -Dartifact=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 -U
```